# eclipse pydev cannot find my package when trying to run a module

Tags: python-3.x, pydev

I am having issues with Eclipse's pydev not finding my package when trying to run my code. The layout of my project is my_project > src > my_package > modules.py
The PYTHONPATH for the project includes the my_project > src and I have no problems running my tests.
However when I try to run I get the message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gturek/dev/git/moniqua_maps/src/moniqua_maps/moniqua_maps.py", line 11, in <module>
    from moniqua_maps.Resources import Resources
  File "/Users/gturek/dev/git/moniqua_maps/src/moniqua_maps/moniqua_maps.py", line 11, in <module>
    from moniqua_maps.Resources import Resources
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moniqua_maps.Resources'; 'moniqua_maps' is not a package
```

I am stumped.

Changing setting in Eclipse as suggested (launching with python -m) results in a slightly different error message

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gturek/miniforge3/envs/mmaps/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 187, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/Users/gturek/miniforge3/envs/mmaps/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 110, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/Users/gturek/dev/git/moniqua_maps/src/moniqua_maps/moniqua_maps.py", line 11, in <module>
    from moniqua_maps.Resources import Resources
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moniqua_maps.Resources'; 'moniqua_maps' is not a package
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include your full error.

Also, how do you run it in the command line?

If the issue is that you have relative imports, one thing that may make a difference is that you may want to launch with `python -m` when running from inside PyDev (you need to turn on the `Launch modules with "python -m mod.name" instead of "python filename.py").

[image: Launch with python -m]

Comment: Hi Fabio, sorry, I did not realize the full error was missing above. When I tried your suggestion I get a slightly different error message but it still does not work:

Comment: From the command line I usually run it by installing the package with a `pip install -e` option

Comment: I should add that my \_\_init\_\_.py files are all blank, perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the structure of your project inside of PyDev (i.e.: a screenshot of the `pydev package explorer` showing the structure opened up to `moniqua_maps.py`)... maybe you haven't marked your `src` folder as a `PyDev source folder`?

Comment: I definitively added the src folder to the PYTHONPATH. Screenshot added

Comment: One conflict I can find there is that you have a `moniqua_maps` package and a `moniqua_maps.moniqua_maps` module, so, if you current working dir in `moniqua_maps` that could potentially fail... can you check if you rename `moniqua_maps.moniqua_maps.py` to `moniqua_maps._moniqua_maps.py` if it works? Also, it'd be nice if you could put at the top of that file: `import sys;print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path)));import moniqua_maps;print(moniqua_maps.__file)` to diagnose if that's really resolving to the inner file and your actual pythonpath being used.

Comment: Hi Fabio, Changing name to _moniqua_maps solved the problem, thank you. Is this an "issue" with Eclipse since it  is not on the command line?

Comment: The issue is not really with Eclipse itself, it depends on your current working directory (so, you were running with one cwd inside eclipse and another cwd out of Eclipse -- in theory it'll also fail in the command line if you run in the same cwd you're using in Eclipse).